# finance yahoo api company profile

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, yahoo-finance

I'm trying to pull the company profile from yahoo finance. I can't seem to find any documentation which provides the URL for Company Info extraction. As of right now I am using the finance-yahoo gem, but that only provides quantitative data. Does anyone know where or how I can extract the company info per symbol?

Answer (score 0):

http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=yhoo (to get Company & Exchange)
The following YQL queries get me closer to the correct result than just fetching the pages. To get the Company and Market:

```
 select h2,span from html where url="http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=YHOO" and xpath='//div[@class="yfi_quote_summary"]/div[1]'
```

Return

```
<div>
    <h2>Yahoo! Inc.</h2>
    <span>(NasdaqGS: YHOO)</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry I should've been more explicit. I need the company profile. Can't seem to find this info in the YQL queries. Thanks,

http://finance.yahoo.com/q/pr?s=YHOO+Profile

Answer (score 0):

The yahoo API closed a few years ago, quantmod used to extract financials, now you have to web scrape with Rvest or similar the only built in financial library extracts filings direct from SEC filings and is called finreportr( search duckduckgo as I might not have the syntax correct).